# AngularJS error loading Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a really dumb problem but I don't know how to fix it. I have this `index.html` file with AngularJS loaded. I'm using Plunker to test the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="BodyController">
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

And this `script.js` file with this information:

```
var BodyController = function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Hi Angular!"
}
```

In the inspector it says:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'BodyController' is not a function, got undefined
```

The script is loaded. I have defined the controller in the JS file and attach the `ng-controller` directive, so I don't know where this can fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very [basic](https://angularjs.org/#the-basics) of AngularJS.

You first need to create a [module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module):

```
var fooApp = angular.module("foo", [])
```

And then, register your controller there:

```
var BodyController = function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Hi Angular!"
}
fooApp.controller("BodyController", BodyController);
```

And, in your `HTML` tag, change your `ng-app` like this:

```
<html ng-app="foo"></html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the controller to your Angular module.

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('BodyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Hi Angular!"
})
```

More info on how to setup a controller
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Answer (score 3):

In HTML, add

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
```

and the script is

```
angular.module('myapp', []).controller('BodyController',BodyController)
```

Answer (score 1):

There were several errors

1. `ng-app` was not set
2. angular module was not defined
3. the controller was not defined

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('BodyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Hi Angular!"
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="BodyController">
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```